# Javascript merge array values belonging to different keys in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an object like this:

```
data = {
    0: [{name: 'ABC', age: '43'}, {name: 'DEF', age: '20'}],
    1: [{name: 'GHI', age: '41'}, {name: 'JKL', age: '25'}],
    2: [{name: 'MNO', age: '19'}, {name: 'PQR', age: '24'}]
};
```

I want to merge the array values of the keys, and make a single array of objects like this:

```
[ {name: 'ABC', age: '43'}, {name: 'DEF', age: '20'}, {name: 'GHI', age: '41'}, {name: 'JKL', age: '25'}, {name: 'MNO', age: '19'}, {name: 'PQR', age: '24'} ]
```

I went through the Lodash [docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4) to find something, but cannot come up with the right combination. Does anyone know how to do this in a concise way, with Lodash (preferably), or something else? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to convert the *array like object* to an `array`, then flatten it.

```js
data = {
    0: [{name: 'ABC', age: '43'}, {name: 'DEF', age: '20'}],
    1: [{name: 'GHI', age: '41'}, {name: 'JKL', age: '25'}],
    2: [{name: 'MNO', age: '19'}, {name: 'PQR', age: '24'}]
};

console.log(
  _.flatten(_.toArray(data))
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Extract the arrays using `_.values()`, and apply concat to the arrays:

```js
var data = {
    0: [{name: 'ABC', age: '43'}, {name: 'DEF', age: '20'}],
    1: [{name: 'GHI', age: '41'}, {name: 'JKL', age: '25'}],
    2: [{name: 'MNO', age: '19'}, {name: 'PQR', age: '24'}]
};

var result = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], _.values(data));
    
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without lodash, just plain old JS:

```
var data = {
    0: [{name: 'ABC', age: '43'}, {name: 'DEF', age: '20'}],
    1: [{name: 'GHI', age: '41'}, {name: 'JKL', age: '25'}],
    2: [{name: 'MNO', age: '19'}, {name: 'PQR', age: '24'}]
};

var result = [];
for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result = result.concat(data[key]);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the new `Object.values()` you may do as follows in pure JS ES6;

```js
var data = { 0: [{name: 'ABC', age: '43'}, {name: 'DEF', age: '20'}],
             1: [{name: 'GHI', age: '41'}, {name: 'JKL', age: '25'}],
             2: [{name: 'MNO', age: '19'}, {name: 'PQR', age: '24'}]
           },
 newData = [].concat(...Object.values(data));
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another pure javascript version.

```js
var data = {
    0: [{name: 'ABC', age: '43'}, {name: 'DEF', age: '20'}],
    1: [{name: 'GHI', age: '41'}, {name: 'JKL', age: '25'}],
    2: [{name: 'MNO', age: '19'}, {name: 'PQR', age: '24'}]
};

var newdata = Object.keys(data).reduce(function (a,b) { 
  return a.concat(data[b]);
}, []);

console.log(newdata);
```